# Regular expresion for detecting a string where position 25-27 is not 348

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression that matches 24 digit followed by 348 followed by a digit or char

```
^[0-9]{24}(348)[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

I need the same, but that accept every thing but `348` in position `25-27`. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead in your regex:

```
^[0-9]{24}(?!348)[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7nbe05/1)

- `(?!348)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if we `348` after first 24 digits
- `[0-9]{3}` matches next 3 digits at position `25-27`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
^(?!.{24}348)\d{27}[a-zA-Z\d]$
```

See the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dXfQsC/11)

- `^` - Start string ancor.
- `(?!.{24}348)` - Negative lookahead for 24 characters followed by `348`.
- `\d{27}` - 27 digits.
- `[a-zA-Z\d]` - Character class for a single letter or digit.
- `$` - End string ancor.

[image]

<sup>**Note:** The same pattern can be written like: `^(?!.{24}348)[0-9]{27}[a-zA-Z0-9]$`.</sup>